# why this axios request give me an error of 403 code , the request give response sucessfully in the api tester but gives the 403 error in the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
useEffect(() => {
   
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axiosPrivate.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/tm/NewManagmentRequests",{
         
        }); 
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setTableData(response.data); 
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to fetch data from the backend.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData(); // Call the fetchData function when the component mounts
  }, []);
```

myspringboot backend allows me to make request from the localhost:3000 port

[error in the console when try to load  data to the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJYCe.png)

I tried  a fetch request it  also went futile ,  then i tried clering my cookies which was ineffective

[springboot backend demoapplication allowing localhost:3000 requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxMby.png)

Comment: Please check whether the API method is `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: The status 403 indicates that the API expects the autorization and front end is not providing that Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Comment: Gotcha!! I added these 2 lines  importing the useAxiosPrivate import useAxiosPrivate from "../../hooks/useAxiosPrivate"; and creating an instance of it const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();  it worked!!!